# capture list for function in swift

Tags: swift, function, closures, automatic-ref-counting

When use closure we can avoid **strong reference cycle** by using `weak` or `unowned` for capture list.

I know that the function is also a named closure. So I guess function also capture values from the context.

How can I avoid **strong reference cycle** for function?

### Codes below

```
class Person {
    var name: String?

    func printInfo() {
        print(self.name ?? "nil")
    }

    deinit {
         print("\(self.name ?? "") is deinitialized.")
    }
}

var p1: Person? = Person()
p1?.name = "Person1"

var printFunction = p1?.printInfo
p1 = nil
```

Not print any message

```
...
p1 = nil
printFunction = nil
```

print `Person1 is deinitialized.`

Does anyone have a solution to this case? In **closure** case we have `weak`, `unowned` capture list.

Comment: Well your function wouldn't exist if `self` did not exist. But in the case of closures, they may exist even after the calling method ceases to exist, which is why they have capture lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the method with a closure.

```
class Person {
    var name: String?

    lazy var printInfo = { [unowned self] in
        print(self.name ?? "nil")
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(self.name ?? "") is deinitialized.")
    }
}


var p1: Person? = Person()
p1?.name = "Person1"

var printFunction = p1?.printInfo

p1 = nil
```

This code print - `Person1 is deinitialized.`

lazy ensures that the access to the property will occur exactly after the initialization of the instance, so the `self` will definitely exist and we can use the `self` in the closure body.
if you need more information read about ARC - https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: I'know that using closure to capture self weakly, but my question is how to capture self weakly in function. I asked to apple developer. he also said there is no way to capture self weakly in swift function.